# Select multiple columns by date, count occurrence for each column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get this query...

```
    SELECT `Num_1`, COUNT(`Num_1`) AS `value_occurrence` FROM numbers WHERE MONTH(`Dates`) = 1 AND YEAR(`Dates`) = 1995 GROUP BY `Num_1` ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC
```

But for multiple columns as in 'Num_1', 'Num_2', 'Num_3', 'Num_4', 'Num_5' and return with the occurrence of each column such as 'num_1_occurrence', 'num_2_occurrence', 'num_3_occurrence', 'num_4_occurrence', 'num_5_occurrence' and all within the date specified.

[numbers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKcMP.png)
[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzjIR.png)

I had tried using...

```
    SELECT `Num_1`,`Num_2`, `Num_3`,`Num_4`,`Num_5`,COUNT(`Num_1`,`Num_2`,`Num_3`,`Num_4`,`Num_5`) AS `num_1_occurrence`,`num_2_occurrence`,`num_3_occurrence`, `num_4_occurrence`,`num_5_occurrence`FROM numbers WHERE MONTH(`Dates`) = 1 AND YEAR(`Dates`) = 1995
```

but just threw errors, I have searched extensively for days and have not found the correct way to do it.

Comment: Add example data and expected output

Comment: updated post with table and example output image, the output is just like I want it but need it for all  columns

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT n.num
     , MAX(IF(n.q='n1',n.cnt,NULL)) AS num_1_occurrence
     , MAX(IF(n.q='n2',n.cnt,NULL)) AS num_2_occurrence
     , MAX(IF(n.q='n3',n.cnt,NULL)) AS num_3_occurrence
  FROM (
         SELECT 'n1'            AS q
              , n1.Num_1        AS num
              , COUNT(n1.Num_1) AS cnt
           FROM numbers n1
          WHERE n1.Dates   >= '1995-01-01'
            AND n1.Dates   <  '1995-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
          GROUP BY n1.Num_1

          UNION ALL

         SELECT 'n2'            AS q
              , n2.Num_2        AS num
              , COUNT(n2.Num_2) AS cnt
           FROM numbers n2
          WHERE n2.Dates   >= '1995-01-01'
            AND n2.Dates   <  '1995-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
          GROUP BY n2.Num_2

          UNION ALL

         SELECT 'n3'            AS q
              , n3.Num_3        AS num
              , COUNT(n3.Num_3) AS cnt
           FROM numbers n3
          WHERE n3.Dates   >= '1995-01-01'
            AND n3.Dates   <  '1995-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
          GROUP BY n3.Num_3
       ) n
 GROUP BY n.num
 ORDER BY GREATEST(num_1_occurrence,num_2_occurrence,num_3_occurrence) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only doing Num_1 and Num_2 here, but I think it's what you're looking for, or close. This will give you the list in "tall" format, with the original column name, the value in that column, and the count of that value in that column going across...

```
SELECT 'Num_1' AS field_name, Num_1 AS value, value_count
FROM (SELECT Num_1, COUNT(Num_1) AS value_count 
      FROM numbers 
      GROUP BY Num_1) AS num1_counts
WHERE MONTH(`Dates`) = 1 AND YEAR(`Dates`) = 1995

UNION 

SELECT 'Num_2' AS field_name, Num_2 AS value, value_count
FROM (SELECT Num_2, COUNT(Num_2) AS value_count 
      FROM numbers 
      GROUP BY Num_2) AS num2_counts
WHERE MONTH(`Dates`) = 1 AND YEAR(`Dates`) = 1995
```